# How does Java's Scanner (System.in) input's buffering actually work?

Tags: java

Over the last days, I've being reading questions as the one that follows: "Why is my input code not working?" I myself had a couple times problems getting the input working right...

as far as good, i found a couple solutions to avoid the problem like typing `nextLine()` to flush the buffer. But I'm still not sure what am I doing.

I think that `Scanner(somefile)` looks simpler to understand to me, since every character (including space or enter) are written on the file. But does it work the same way when we get the input from the keyboard? When I ask for an Integer for example (using `nextInt()` ), and then I give the number in the command-line and press 'intro', why is that `\n` staying on the buffer?

Could anyone help us understand it by giving a step-by-step answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Java Docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29) About `nextInt()`

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. If the translation is successful, *the scanner advances past the input that matched.*

This method consumes the integer, but not the new-line character or other character after that integer. 
So after consumption of integer by `nextInt()`, there only remain newline character (In this case) as entered by keyboard or file. It cannot discarded by `nextInt()`. Thus `\n` staying on the buffer.

And description of [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) says

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

As we expected by `nextLine()`, it consumes the new-line character that was not consumed by `nextInt()`. But when it return it exclude newline so returned string by `nextLine()` becomes empty.

Comment: So we are doomed to clean the buffer after every nextInt?

Comment: Or you can take input by nextLine() and convert it using Integer.parseInt().

Comment: I do that often, but then I don't know how to match it with a hasNextInt(), for example in a while loop (while (scan.HasNextInt()))... I think once it is parsed is ripped off the buffer

Comment: In that case we need extra nextLine() to ripped off the buffer. I have no other idea how to handle that condition.